# grep string from log file named with today's date

Tags: bash, shell, grep

So I have a script that grabs a list of IPs and other info from a source every hour and outputs a file named `%d%m%Y-%H.csv`

I want to grep these IPs and output them into another file named `IP_%d%m%Y-%H`.
However, I can't seem to get the code just right, it basically returns an empty file and I presume it just can't read the original file.

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" %d%m%Y-%H.csv>>IP_%d%m%Y-%H.txt;
done
```

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: what's the error you getting when you run? "I presume it just can't read the original file."? What does that mean? What is in the file "%d%m%Y-%H.csv"?

Comment: try `grep -Po "..."`   operators `|` and `?` need `-P` or `-E`  options

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, however: are you sure you need a so complicated regex? You are not validating IPs, you are just filtering them. "Four numbers separated by three dots" should suffice in your situation.

Comment: The regex is to avoid having strings like 888.333.111.222 being greped if they were to happen.

Comment: To almas, the error I'm getting is "%d%m%Y-%H.csv: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want the actual date eg. 10022015-16.csv

Then your script will have to be:

```
#!/bin/bash

NOW=$(date +%d%m%Y-%H)

grep -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" $NOW.csv>>IP_$NOW.txt
exit $?
```

[edit] modified the exit statement, and the date statement as suggested by Jotne.

Comment: Hi Christian, this was exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: You should not use old and outdated back tics, use parentheses: `NOW=$(date +%d%m%Y-%H)`

Comment: sorry I am old =)... fixed it.